# How to make a Symfony GET form redirect to route with parameter?

Tags: forms, get, symfony

I want to create a form for searching a profile by username which redirect then to the profile page of the user. Btw, I use Symfony 3.2.

I reckon the natural way for doing this would be a GET action form. It would even allow a customer to change the url directly with the good username to see its profile.

Here is the code of my controller :

<kbd>ProfileController.php</kbd>

```php
//...

/** @Route("/profil/search", name="profil_search") */
public function searchAction() {          
    $builder = $this->createFormBuilder();
    $builder                
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('profil_show'))
        ->setMethod('GET')
        ->add('username', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Username : '))
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Search'));
    $form = $builder->getForm();

    return $this->render('profils/profil_search.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}   

/** @Route("/profil/show/{username}", name="profil_show") */
public function showAction($username) {      
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User');
    $searchedUser = $repository->findOneByUsername($username);

    return $this->render('profils/profil_show.html.twig', [
        'searchedUser' => $searchedUser,
    ]);
}   

//...
```

This code will lead to the following error message :

> Some mandatory parameters are missing ("username") to generate a URL for
>   route "profil_show".

I read the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/action_method.html) thoroughly but couldn't guess, how can I pass the `username` variable to the `profil_show` route as a parameter ?

If my way of doing is not the good one, thanks for telling me in comments but I'd still like to know how to use GET forms.

**EDIT :**

Thanks to @MEmerson answer, I get it now. So for future noobs like me, here is how I did it :

```php
/** @Route("/profil/search", name="profil_search") */
public function searchAction(Request $request) {     
    $data = array();
    $builder = $this->createFormBuilder($data);
    $builder                
        //->setAction($this->generateUrl('profil_show'))
        //->setMethod('GET')
        ->add('username', SearchType::class, array('label' => 'Username : '))
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Search'));
    $form = $builder->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('profil_show', array('username' => $data["username"]));
    }

    return $this->render('profils/profil_search.html.twig', [
        'method' => __METHOD__,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'message' => $message,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the error message it says that the problem is where you are trying to generate the URL for the path 'profil_show'.

Your controller annotations require that the URL be populated with a user name

```
/** @Route("/profil/show/{username}", name="profil_show") */
```

this means that Symfony is expecting http://yoursite.com/profil/show/username for the route. But if you want to pass it as a GET form posting it really should be expecting http://yoursite.com/profil/show?username

you can add a second route or change your existing route to be

```
/** @Route("/profil/show", name="profil_show_search") */
```

that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. I thought GET method would be able to redirect to route as in your first link. I'll stick with POST and redirect in the controller on submit then.